# Matomo Tracking with Custom Variables get summed up/overwritten

Tags: analytics, matomo, piwiktracker

I’m trying to track page views using custom variables but I can’t get it right. For instance, if some user has logged in and opened Article A once + Article B twice, I assume to get “1” for Article A and “2” for Article B in a report.

But when I use page scope custom variables (cvar argument), it summarizes page views and returns “3” for each article.

```
[matomoSite]/matomo.php?cvar={"1":["article_id","A"]}&e_c=Content&e_a=Details&e_n=Article&idsite=6&rec=1&_id=af344a398df83894&uid=150&rand=123457
[matomoSite]/matomo.php?cvar={"1":["article_id","B"]}&e_c=Content&e_a=Details&e_n=Article&idsite=6&rec=1&_id=af344a398df83895&uid=150&rand=123458
```

When I use visit scope custom variables (_cvar argument), it overwrites previously recorded data and returns “0” for Articls A and “3” for Article B, which is incorrect, too.

```
[matomoSite]/matomo.php?_cvar={"1":["article_id","A"]}&e_c=Content&e_a=Details&e_n=Article&idsite=6&rec=1&_id=af344a398df83896&uid=150&rand=123459
[matomoSite]/matomo.php?_cvar={"1":["article_id","B"]}&e_c=Content&e_a=Details&e_n=Article&idsite=6&rec=1&_id=af344a398df83897&uid=150&rand=123460
```

I actually don’t need to group it by session or user, just an ordinary page views count. (I have to mention that there’re 2 possible kinds of a page view - “Dashboard” and “Details”, that’s why I pass event tracking info - e_c, e_a).

Comment: So we ended up composing a custom SQL to get the needed data from the Matomo database.